# SP 2013 user profiles keep reverting to old profile information

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service

I have this issue where we have a script that updates user profiles if there has been changes to their profile which as being changed in a custom list. this script runs every night.

however recently i noticed. all profiles have gone back to the old profiles and no matter how much change i make, they always go back to the old one. tried manually editing the profile from the UPA and running the script to update UP not still nothing.

is this due to the AD sync happening every 1 am? But what is odd is that in the people picker of sharepoint site. when i add people in sharepoint groups, people picker displays that correct profile (I undertsant that people picker is retrieved from AD) but when i click add, the added user has the wrong profile (profile in UPA).

this means that the profiles in AD are most likely correct (i have no access to the AD so i wouldn't know and AD team is not being helpful) and that the sync must sync from AD to SharePoint UPA but what's happening is that the information is being reverted to the old info and i am not sure what i am already missing.

Comment: Could you share your script for update of profiles and reason for running it (that shouldn't be necessary). You can use as well tool like AD explorer to browse through AD (you could use same account as for the profile sync to query it if  your account doesn't have correct rights)

Comment: oh so basically previous enggrs created that script bec. the company setup is that management can modify employee's info such as number, name, job title, etc in a custom sp list and it would sync to sharepoint user profile, hence the script created

Comment: but then the user profile sync with AD would overwrite it, doesn't seems to be right. Maybe script is updating the AD and that it what is failing now? Other option is that those fields were excluded from sync and someone has added the fields to sync by mistake? Check the sync options and try excluding those fields.

Comment: the script for updating UP is just the basic getUserProfile, $up["field"].value then commit. nothing special to update the AD